# java managing worker-thread deaths

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have a main thread that spawns a bunch of "worker-threads" that works alongside it for the duration of the process. What I want is that if a worker-thread dies from an exception or whatnot, the main thread should also throw a runtime-exception and die peacefully.

This can be achieved by catching the exception in the worker-tread and setting an error-flag before exiting. The main thread then polls this flag and throws an exception if it's set. This can be done by try-catch or setting an exception handler.

My question is whether there's a simpler way that doesn't include polling in the main thread. Something that goes automatic if you know what I mean.

Edit: 
Well, many claim that setting a handler is the answer and that this is a duplicate. Well, unless I'm mistaking things here, the handler is executed by the thread that throws the exception in the first place, so I still have to set a flag to kill the main thread. I thought this was clear. SO let me clarify;

What I want is that if a worker-thread dies from an exception or whatnot, the main thread should also throw a runtime-exception and die peacefully, **without using flags**, but have it done "automatically"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362345/defining-one-global-uncaughtexceptionhandler-for-all-threads-of-my-application

Comment: Nope, it's not the same question

Comment: Well it's not _exactly_ the same question, but very similar and the thread contains everything you need.

Comment: Not exactly, but UncaughtExceptionHandle is your go-to implementation here.

Comment: Ok, the problem as I see it is that given my own experience the uncaughtExceptionHandler works no different than a try-catch block and I have to set a flag in either case, since the handler is executed  by a worker-thread and not by the main thread, just as I've written. That still means I have to poll some state in the main thread. At least that's what I had to do when I tried it the last time.

Comment: What is the main thread going to _do_ when it sees the flag set?  Why can't the exception handler for the dying thread just do the same thing instead of asking the main thread to do it?

Comment: I want the main thread to throw a runtime exception. That's my question. Can one thread make another thread to throw an exception directly, without flags

Answer (score 0):

Have a `CountdownLatch` in the main thread, have it wait on the `CountdownLatch`.

When a thread exits decrement the `CountdownLatch`. When that happens have the main thread act appropriately.