# SLF4J-LOG4J How to save in the log file also the uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, runtimeexception

I'm using slf4j/log4j in my java application. 
My problem is that for now I'm able only to log exceptions stack traces calling the appropriate logger method in the catch section of a try catch like:

```
catch (AnException ex) {
    logger.error("An exception occurred", ex); 
}
```

I would like to put in the log file also the runtime exception for which I didn't put any cacth, like NullPointerException or NumberFormatException.
As they are shown in the console I guess that there is a manner to redirect this stream from the console to the SLF4J logger. 
Anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: Thread class has a method to register an uncaught exception handler.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log *unchecked* exceptions, catch [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and log them.
To log *all* exceptions, catch [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and log them.
To also log errors, catch [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) and log them.

For command-line programs, you'd likely want to do this in the `main()` method, in a `try` block started *after* initializing the logging framework.

If you use threads, you'd want to do this in the `run()` method of the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) / [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

In a Servlet web application, you might do that in a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), and rethrow the exception so container can handle error correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it should work. 
BTW I guess if there is a better way to manage it, this seems a bit a workaround.  I will wait to see if anyone has a better idea then eventually mark your as the choosen answer

Answer (score 0):

I would like to highlight an other solution that works for uncaught exceptions globally in your application, without wrapping with try/catch blocks each time.

Threads have an field called `uncaughtExceptionHandler` used whenever an uncaught exception rises. This field can be overridden using the method `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler)` once in your startup main method for instance. Each time an uncaught exception rises your custom UncaughtExceptionHandler will be used to handle it.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362345/defining-one-global-uncaughtexceptionhandler-for-all-threads-of-my-application) for more details.